# Converting Java To Kotlin: Type mismatch. Required: MenuSlidingTabStrip.OnTabSelectedListener? Found: (Nothing, Nothing) → Boolean

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-interop

I am converting an Android app that was originally written in Java to Kotlin.
I am struggling to understand the following error message:

> Type mismatch.
> Required:
> MenuSlidingTabStrip.OnTabSelectedListener?
> Found:
> (Nothing, Nothing) → Boolean

Here is the fragment of code where the error is being signalled (and it was working perfectly fine before the conversion):

```
private var tabs: MenuSlidingTabStrip? = null //The Kotlinized class

        tabs!!.setOnTabSelectedListner{ tab, category -> /*Type mismatch...*/
            listView!!.post {
            ...
            }
        }
```

The issue arose after converting this Java code (found in MenuSlidingTabStrip) :

```
public void setOnTabSelectedListner(OnTabSelectedListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public interface OnTabSelectedListener {
    public void OnTabSelected(View tab, MenuCategory category);

}
```

To Kotlin

```
  fun setOnTabSelectedListner(listener: OnTabSelectedListener?) {
    this.listener = listener
}

interface OnTabSelectedListener {
    fun onTabSelected(tab: View?, category: MenuCategory?)
}
```

Can you see the issue? Do you need more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use the **natively supported lambdas** as:

```kotlin
// make `this.listener` look like lambda signature as well
fun setOnTabSelectedListner(listener: (tab: View?, category: MenuCategory?) -> Unit) {
    this.listener = listener
}

tabs!!.setOnTabSelectedListner { tab, category ->
    // ...
}
```

If you still wanna use the SAM conversion with the manually defined interface, then mark the interface with the `fun` keyword as described in [Kotlin 1.4-M1 Release changelog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/03/kotlin-1-4-m1-released/) (will only work with Kotlin 1.4):

```kotlin
fun interface OnTabSelectedListener {
    fun onTabSelected(tab: View?, category: MenuCategory?)
}

// call that method like this:
tabs!!.setOnTabSelectedListner(OnTabSelectedListener { tab, category ->
    // ...
})
```

If you've not switched to Kotlin-1.4 (which is still in beta state), you have to manually instantiate the anonymous object if you are not willing to use the natively provided lambda syntax:

```kotlin
tabs!!.setOnTabSelectedListner(object : OnTabSelectedListener {
    override fun onTabSelected(tab: View?, category: MenuCategory?) {
        // ...
    }
})
```

Comment: Kudos for giving multiple solutions to this problem, currently throughout the code I am manually instantiating anonymous objects which looks just ugly. Didn't see it here at first. Already planning to refactor every usage to manually defined interface once Kotlin 1.4 will become stable.